# How to return response to another functional component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, fetch-api, react-functional-component

I am facing one issue that is I have created a functional component for API calling where I am getting params and API name as function parameter. Inside this method I am calling API with fetch & I am getting response too but when I am returning the response then it showing me undefined. What is the issue in it?

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("apikey", Constant.API_KEY);
formData.append("email", email);

ApiCall.ApiCalling(formData, Constant.forget_password)
  .then((data) => {
      console.log('Response -> ', data); // Here getting undefined
  })


// New component ApiCall.js
export default {
    async ApiCalling(params, apiName) {

        await NetInfo.fetch().then(async state => {
            if (state.isConnected == true) {

                console.log(Constant.BASE_URL + apiName);
                console.log(params);

                await fetch(Constant.BASE_URL + apiName, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: params
                })
                    .then(results => results.json())
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log("Response - ", response); // Here getting  
                                                                 proper response
                        return response;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch 
                        operation: ' + error.message);
                        throw error;
                    });

            } else {
                alert("Please connect with internet")
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: try to remove first promise resolver. you can get (response) -> console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`). Hopo it help you.

Comment: Same issue occur with this also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// New component ApiCall.js
export default {
async ApiCalling(params, apiName) {
var result;  // Create one variable
await NetInfo.fetch().then(async state => {
    if (state.isConnected == true) {

        console.log(Constant.BASE_URL + apiName);
        console.log(params);

        await fetch(Constant.BASE_URL + apiName, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: params
        })
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("Response - ", response);
                result = response;  // Assign response to that variable
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch 
                operation: ' + error.message);
                throw error;
            });

      } else {
        alert("Please connect with internet")
      }
    });
    return result; // Return the response
 }
```